# Creating shortcuts for duplicate tab

Tags: conemu

Is it possible to create keyboard shortcut for "duplicate root..." which comes when right-clicking on any tab?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmder: make a new tab open in the directory of the already-open tab](http://superuser.com/questions/912722/cmder-make-a-new-tab-open-in-the-directory-of-the-already-open-tab)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is "Try to duplicate tab with current state of root process" item on "Keys & Macro" settings page.

Was renamed to "Duplicate tab with current state of root process" in build 130223.

Comment: Thanks Maximus

I was not having this build, So I didn't get this.

Comment: Any idea how to remove a confirmation dialog "Do you want to duplicate ...?" ?

Comment: Use GuiMacro: Shell("new_console:I")

Comment: Based on your previous comment, I created a macro (in cmder) with this GuiMacro: 'Shell("new_console:I")' and then bound it to a keyboard shortcut. I've been searching for this functionality for ages. Recommend posting a separate answer for this. Thanks, Maximus.