# cmder: make a new tab open in the directory of the already-open tab

Tags: windows, command-line, conemu, cmder

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in [Cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/), I want the new tab to open in the same directory as the old tab (the tab that I was in, when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

This will avoid a lot of `cd` commands in the new tab, to get to the same working directory as the old tab.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As explained by @Maximus here and also in [another question](https://superuser.com/a/556378/31419), a nice way to do this is to bind

```
Shell("new_console:I")
```

to a GuiMacro hotkey.

In cmder/ConEmu, go to `Settings|Keys&Macro`. Then click the `Macros` radio button on the top right and then add a new macro for  `Shell("new_console:I")` and bind it to whatever key combination (hotkey) you want.

[image: Add New Macro with HotKey]

So in my case (see screenshot above) pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> creates a new tab in the same directory as the current tab (i.e. duplicates the current tab). Have been searching for how to do this for ages, so I thought it was worth an answer instead of just a comment.

And yes, I can confirm that this works perfectly fine in cmder (tested in v1.2), as cmder uses ConEmu under the hood.

Thanks to @Maximus.

Comment: new_console:I doesn't open in the same path for me. ConEmu 151115 [64]

Comment: Just what I needed.

Comment: @rofrol Check http://superuser.com/a/942854/216090 for how to open the new tab in the same path as current tab.

Comment: `new_console:I` does work for me in ConEmu

Answer (score 1):

In ConEmu you can call "Duplicate root" from [TabMenu](http://conemu.github.io/en/TabMenu.html) and you may choose any desired hotkey on the [Keys & Macro](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html) Settings page.

BTW, you may [split](http://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html) (to right/bottom) your active tab.

Comment: Can you please explain how this is used?  Can it be mapped to a shortcut key? — the OP is explicitly trying to reduce tedious typing.  Do you know whether this works in Cmder?

Comment: cmder IS ConEmu. OP may set up any desired hotkey to this action.

Comment: How I can call "Duplicate root", what is that? Can you be a little more details for a poor Cmder mortal ;)

Comment: Some more details and links.

Comment: this worked for me http://superuser.com/a/935109/64577