# Open A New Tab In ConEmu, in the same Directory (git bash)

Tags: conemu, git-bash

I want to assign a keyboard short cut within ConEmu that will open a new tab, in the same directory as the current tab is within.

So something like:

```
-new_console:d:[<pwd>]%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
```

where **`[<pwd>]`** runs pwd or grabs the $PWD environment variable. Or any command that would get the current working directory.

--UPDATE---

Currently I have a bash script set up:

```
winpwda()
{
    pwd | sed -e 's/\//\\/g ' | sed 's/^.//' | sed 's/^c/C:/g'
}
nc()
{
 ConEmu.exe -new_console:d:"$(winpwda)" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Git\bin\sh.exe" &
}
```

running "nc" will now open a new window with a git bash ConEmu in the current directory. Annoyingly if I use "cmd" instead of "ConEmu.exe" it successfully opens it in a new tab instead of a new window. Also not sure how i can assign a bash argument as a keyboard short cut...

Comment: ConEmu.exe? It doesn't have switch -new_console. You must use proper executable to get proper result! Ex. `ConEmuC -c bash.exe ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ConEmu's [docs clearly state](http://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#What_you_shall_do_to_get_CD_support) what user shall to configure.

For bash user has to add to bash profile

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'
```

And set up a call of `Shell` [function](http://conemu.github.io/en/GuiMacro.html#Shell) in the [Keys&Macros](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsHotkeys.html). Example assumes you have {Git bash} task.

```
Shell("new_console", "{Git bash}", "", "%CD%")
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I was definitely on the wrong track, I was looking at "Startup->Tasks->HotKey". So I assigned "Shell("new_console", "{Git bash}", "", "%CD%")" as a macro and added PROMPT_COMMAND to my bashrc but it fails with "directory name is invalid" %CD%

Comment: Also "PROMPT_COMMAND='ConEmuC -StoreCWD'" throws this error: Parsing command line failed (/C argument not found):
"c:\Program Files (x86)\EliteTools\ConEmuPack.140812\ConEmu\ConEmuC.exe" -StoreCWD

Comment: Really? Version from what year you are using?

Comment: I also needed to put

```
if [ -n "${ConEmuWorkDir}" ]; then
  cd "$ConEmuWorkDir"
fi
```

to my .bashrc, see [tips here](https://conemu.github.io/en/CygwinStartDir.html).