# Open a new tab in ConEmu, in the same directory (WSL)

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tabs, conemu

Trying to achieve the same as [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/942835/open-a-new-tab-in-conemu-in-the-same-directory-git-bash)
But with WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

[ConEmu documentation](https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html#What_you_shall_do_to_get_CD_support) states that shell via PS1 and ANSI:
`This is the only option available for Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.`

I set this on `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ -n "${ConEmuPID}" ]]; then
  PS1="$PS1\[\e]9;9;\"\w\"\007\e]9;12\007\]"
fi
```

Then I set up a call of Shell function in the Keys&Macros.

```
Shell("new_console", "{WSL bash}", "", "%CD%")
```

Having a `{WSL bash}` task which uses `conemu-cyg-64.exe`.

```
set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl -C~ -cur_console:pm:/mnt -new_console:t:WSL
```

But no luck...
Opening new tabs do not open them in same directory as last one.