# Cmder new cmd console

Tags: windows, conemu, cmder

I use cmder@1.3. I want to split a window with new tabs. I found how to do this [here](https://conemu.github.io/en/SplitScreen.html#From-your-shell-prompt). So as I understood I type `cmd -new_console:s` and I get a new pane. Fine, it works. But I get [this](https://prnt.sc/igwf8u). I get standard cmd but just in cmder. It does not have functions the original pane has and it looks different as you can see. My origin pane view is [here](http://prntscr.com/igwgt5) where I can use cmder functions (e.g. aliases).

How to use `cmd -new_console:s` so that it load cmd with cmder functionality not just bare cmd?

**PS**: I have a hotkey for duplicating a tab as [here](https://superuser.com/questions/912722/cmder-make-a-new-tab-open-in-the-directory-of-the-already-open-tab) is written. As I can see there is `Shell("new_console:I")` for a hotkey. I tried `cmd -new_console:sI` but it did not change anything.

Comment: This is a product support question for a very obscure product. You might be better off asking the guy who wrote it.

Comment: Official documentation should be the first place to find answers. [-new_console](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html) and [Tasks](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html)!

Answer (score 0):

I can not explain the answer but at least it could help someone searching here. Thanks to @Maximus I found that my default task was `{cmd:Cmder}` with such a command `cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"  -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%`. From this it is clear that we should call `cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"` before `-new_console` not just `cmd -new_console`. I found that `init.bat` contains init functions and setup. Do not understand why it can not be by default by it is a solution at least.

So, calling `cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat"` could be a little tricky as for me so I created an cmder alias in CmderRoot/config/user-aliases.cmd. The alias looks as follows: `concmd=cmd /k "%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" $*`. Now you can easy call `concmd -new_console` with needed argument and enjoy. `concmd` is an alias, you can replace it whatever word you want.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer, I made 3 tabs open at the start cmd with this on "settings-> Startup/tasks:

```
-new_console:d:C:\Users\izz\Documents\project1 cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "

-new_console:d:C:\Users\izz\Documents\project2 cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "

-new_console:d:C:\Users\izz\Documents\project3 cmd /k ""%ConEmuDir%\..\init.bat" "
```